# How does dispatcher work?

Tags: solaris

This is a general Operating Systems theory question but since I am learning OS theory through UNIX-like systems I wanted to ask it here.

Today, after my OS lecture , I asked to our instructor that:
'Dispatcher is a thread , which is inside Process Manager process. Since PM is also a process, while a process called A is in the running state, how does PM take over the processor from it? Dispatcher is supposed to take processor away from processes and allocate it to another process. But while Process Manager is not running, how is that supposed to happen?'

He said: 'Process Manager is "always" in the running state in CPU0'. I said: 'If there is only one CPU with one core, how does PM always in running state?" He said it is.

Any one can light me out of that dilemma?

Comment: note: the process scheduler, if I understand your question correctly, is _not_ a process itself. it's part of the kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An operating system usually "takes a processor away" from a thread of control whenever the running thread makes a system call, or there's a clock interrupt, or some other interrupt occurs.

That is, the running thread invokes the kernel via a `read()` or `write()` or `gettimeofday()` system call.  The system call handler not only does the work for reading or writing or whatever, it also ends up figuring out if it should return to the thread that invoked it, or if something else should run. That "figuring out" is the Process Manager.

A program that's CPU-bound (does not make read/write/open/close system calls) will still have the CPU taken away from it every so often by the timer interrupt. A special clock interrupts the CPU 10 or 60 or 1000 times per second. The interrupt handler, among other things, decides which thread to give the CPU to for the next time slice.

Other interrupts can happen, too, from the mouse, or the keyboard or the network card or the disk drive.

You can say that the "Process Manager" is always runnable because the code in interrupt handlers and system call handlers always calls it.

Comment: @strugee What i meant by Process Manager is also a process is that , dispatcher is a thread. And I doubt that PM is not a process , at least it is a Kernel Thread , which still need to be assigned to processor to do it's work.

"A special clock interrupts" was the answer for my question. Thank you very much. So basically , I suppose there is a special register on the clock that OS writes for defining the time-slice. PM is always Ready , but not running. Bec if it was running , CPU will always be serving to it. I tried to tell that to the instructor. Suppose i couldn't expalin it to him.

Comment: So what is a dispatcher? Did you explain this part or it's the same as *Process Manager* you said? Can I say that dispatcher is just a general idea and *Process Manager* is an implementation of it?

Comment: @ptr_user7813604 - dispatcher/Process Manager/scheduler probably all mean the same thing, a piece of code that decides what non-kernel process to run next, and maybe on what CPU. Unusual operating systems may have different names, or the functions broken out differently and named different things, but the general idea is still there.